# Information needed with Bash/Unix fundamentals

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-lion

I'm struggling to understand how `Bash` works (I'm using Mac OS X Lion).

I use the terminal for things like Git Version Control and SSH'ing onto our servers and doing basic interactions like that. But I don't really understand Bash scripts and the whole unix set-up past that.

So when I need to install software and it asks me to set environment variables (and PATH variables like $PATH e.g. `export PATH=/usr/local/bin`) or add paths to a file like `/usr/local/bin/:usr/bin/:$PATH` - I just have no idea of what I'm doing or more importantly "why" - it is just really confusing to me.

For example, why is there a `/usr/local/bin/` and a `/usr/bin/` (one local and one not?) and why does some software get installed in one and not the other?

And what about files like `.bashrc`, `.profile` and `.bash_profile` - I understand that `.bashrc` is executed when a shell starts up and it checks the paths inside that file for application settings and stuff like that, but why do I not have either `.profile` and `.bash_profile` on my work computer, but on my home laptop I have `.bash_profile` and in some places I've seen articles where people ask the user to set-up a `.profile` if it doesn't exist? Why not just one file for the shell to go to to look for stuff.

I've got NodeJs installed on my laptop at home and that has a path set-up under `.bash_profile`. I've recently tried installing `rvm` so I can try out some Ruby programming (I needed rvm so I could upgrade to the latest version of Ruby) but that has settings inside `.bashrc` such as `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`.

Sorry if I'm just repeating myself, but it seems like there just aren't any good articles about this sort of stuff. Articles are either non-existent OR they are over-kill so you never really understand the bits you're interested in (i.e. I don't want to know everything about UNIX just enough to understand these common items that seem to crop up a lot).

Again, this is a bit of a strange question because there isn't a specific *thing* I want to know, just the common stuff that crops us when you need to install software via the Terminal and you're asked to do things like setting paths and variables and choosing locations of where to install stuff (which bin folder to use) and stuff like that, so a general overview of all this would be amazing!

Any help I can get understanding how the above items work and why would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: It's always good to ask 'One question per question' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions is rather 'general'. So the best I can think of is point you to definitive resources on the topic [which may or may not satisfy you].

1: The TLDP book [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/), especially Chapter 3 on [The Bash environment](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_03.html) which talks about `PATH` and the bash configuration files you mentioned.

2: The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) which basically sets out requirements for how a UNIX(like) Operating System's filesystem should be laid out. The section on [/usr](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEUSRHIERARCHY) goes into considerable detail.

And in case those links go down in the future, here is the gist of what they say about your specific questions:

1: `PATH` is basically an environment variable, which contains a ':' separated list of directories. When you type a command in Bash, Bash will go through the directories (in the order they are listed) listed in `PATH` to search for an executable file corresponding to the command. You can see the current contents of `PATH` by executing:

`echo $PATH`

in your terminal.

2: `/usr` contains files/packages installed by your distribution. In my case [I use 'Archlinux'], this means packages which get installed when I install Archlinux, or which I can choose to install via the official package manager for Archlinux. In your case, I guess this means stuff that came along with Mac OS X, officially packaged by Apple.

`/usr/local` is where things get installed when I locally install packages [bypassing the package management system]. e.g. if I want the latest copy of GCC, I download the sources, build it for myself, and then when I execute 'make install' it goes into /usr/local. But the 'official' copy of GCC that comes with Archlinux goes into /usr. And when that official copy gets updated, my own copy in /usr/local is untouched.

So on a freshly installed system [e.g. a spanking new MacBook], `/usr/local` should be empty. Because the local administrator (you) has installed nothing yet.

Comment: I don't know for sure if the links provided would help, but from the sounds of it, the "Bash Guide for Beginners" sounds like it should be exactly what I need to find out more, so thank you! :-)

Comment: Ps, your other comments re: /usr/ and /usr/local helped also!